# Windows scheduled tasks fail with 0x1, don't log errors

Tags: python, windows-server-2008, windows-task-scheduler

I have three Python scripts running overnight as scheduled tasks on a Windows Server 2008 VM. I can run them manually with no problems. But when I look at the Task Scheduler each morning, the first has run successfully and the subsequent two returned `0x1`. I added an exception handler to all three scripts to log the traceback, hoping to find the guilty operation. I tested the handler by manually raising an `Exception` which was working fine. However, when I checked the next day no log had been created, meaning the script either never ran or didn't actually throw an error. Can anyone shed any light on what exactly `0x1` means, or if there's a situation in which the script would run but still return that?

For what it's worth, this is the batch file that calls the script:

```
@echo off
"E:\Scripts\Backup\create_backup.py"
```

Comment: A quick search seems to indicate that this can be caused by [not specifying the correct working directory](http://www.blogfodder.co.uk/2012/4/20/win-2008-task-scheduler-with-return-code-1-0x1). When testing your setup, did you try to invoke the task execution *through* the task scheduler (there's a *Run* option for tasks in the library)?

Comment: Oliver, thanks for the tip, that does sound exactly like what I'm experiencing. I updated the script path to exclude the current working directory, instead specifying it in "Start in". When I run the task nothing visibly happens in the scheduler (I would expect the status to be "Running..."), but eventually it completes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Look like this problem outside of python.
May be i wrong, but by default windows allow cmd.exe execution only for logged in user.
To check, add diagnostic output to cmd script

> echo Run %DATE% %TIME% >> c:/tmp/file.log